# iOS : A saccade when scrolling between photos from PHAsset

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uipageviewcontroller, phasset

I put in the scrollViewDidScroll() method the method which extract image from PHAsset to display on the view. I do this for the current image, the previous image and the next image. So I have 3 images loaded every times. When I scroll, I destroy images which they are not used.

But when I scroll between views, I have a small jolt. I think it's because the photo to display is loading from PHAsset to my view.

What can I do to fix this ?

Here is my code to charge photos when I enter in the scrollViewDidScroll() method (page is the number of the image) :

```
        let options = PHImageRequestOptions()
        options.resizeMode = PHImageRequestOptionsResizeMode.None
        options.deliveryMode = PHImageRequestOptionsDeliveryMode.HighQualityFormat
        options.version = PHImageRequestOptionsVersion.Current
        options.synchronous = true
        let size:CGSize = CGSizeMake((CGFloat(lastAsset.pixelWidth)*1),(CGFloat(lastAsset.pixelHeight)*1))
        PHImageManager.defaultManager().requestImageForAsset(self.listOfAssets[page], targetSize: size, contentMode: PHImageContentMode.AspectFit, options: options, resultHandler: {(result, info) -> Void in
            self.imagesToDisplay[page] = result!
        })
        scrollView.frame = frame
        let newPageView = UIImageView(image: self.imagesToDisplay[page])
        newPageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
        newPageView.frame = scrollView.bounds

        scrollView.addSubview(newPageView)
        self.subviewsToDisplay[page] = scrollView
        self.mainScrollerView.addSubview(scrollView)
        self.pageViews.replaceObjectAtIndex(page, withObject: scrollView)
```

Comment: Simply mean that you are using too many resources in `didScroll()`. Make it `async` (i.e. load on another proses queue).

Comment: I tried, but it's more long and I have new exceptions when the user is scrolling a little bit more faster.